# How do I retireve the record ID of an account related to a contact in an LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, navigation

Im trying to make an LWC component on the Contact object that displays a link to a related Account. I am using NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl and trying to dynamically pass in the recordId of the related account but it does not seem to work. I am pulling the account Id through the schema.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Account.Name';
import ACCOUNTID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.AccountId';

export default class RelationshipMap extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@track actions = [
    { label: 'Edit', value: 'edit', iconName: 'utility:edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', value: 'delete', iconName: 'utility:delete' },
];
@api recordId;
contactObject = CONTACT_OBJECT;
url;



@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD,ACCOUNT_FIELD,ACCOUNTID_FIELD] })
record;


get nameValue() {
    console.log('url: ' + this.url);
    console.log('accountId: ' + this.accountId);
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
}

get accountName() {
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, ACCOUNT_FIELD) : '';
}

get accountId() {
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, ACCOUNTID_FIELD) : '';
}

connectedCallback() {
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.accountId,
            objectApiName: 'Account',
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    }).then(url => this.url = url);
}
}
```

Do I need to use an apex method instead?

EDIT: Here is updated code after using sfdxfoxs suggestion.

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Name';
import ACCOUNT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.Account.Name';
import ACCOUNTID_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Contact.AccountId';

export default class RelationshipMap extends 
NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
@track actions = [
    { label: 'Edit', value: 'edit', iconName: 'utility:edit' },
    { label: 'Delete', value: 'delete', iconName: 'utility:delete' },
];
@api recordId;
contactObject = CONTACT_OBJECT;
url;


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [NAME_FIELD,ACCOUNT_FIELD,ACCOUNTID_FIELD] })
record = {}
getRecordHandler(result) {
    const { data, error } = this.record = result;
    if (data) {
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
                recordId: getFieldValue(data, ACCOUNTID_FIELD),
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: 'view',
            },
        }).then((url) => (this.url = url));
    } else if(error){
        console.log('Error');
    }
}


get nameValue() {
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, NAME_FIELD) : '';
}

get accountName() {
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, ACCOUNT_FIELD) : '';
}

get accountId() {
    return this.record.data ? getFieldValue(this.record.data, ACCOUNTID_FIELD) : '';
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wire methods return their data after connectedCallback is called. Use a wire handler to do what you're trying to do:

```
@wire(getRecord, {
    recordId: "$recordId",
    fields: [NAME_FIELD, ACCOUNT_FIELD, ACCOUNTID_FIELD],
})
record = {}
getRecordHandler(result) {
    const { data, error } = this.record = result;
    if (data) {
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
            type: "standard__recordPage",
            attributes: {
                recordId: getFieldValue(data, ACCOUNTID_FIELD),
                objectApiName: "Account",
                actionName: "view",
            },
        }).then((url) => (this.url = url));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response it seems very helpful. However, I am getting an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data').

Comment: @Benton Can you update your question with the latest version of your code?

Comment: Ok it is updated it

Comment: @Benton Your getters were crashing because the record variable was removed when we created a wire handler. You can add a new property, as edited in to the answer.

Comment: Ok no errors now but the link is not working. The code is updated in the last edit. Also, I am trying to pass the url as an href attribute in a lighting tile for more context.

Comment: @Benton  wire method will run reactively   make sure to wrap  your url  inside  template  if tag and render only  if url is populated.  <template if:true = {url}> url anchor tag </template>